# What's the alternative for formdata.get() method in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser-cache, form-data

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', 'Chris');
formData.append('username', 'Bob');
formData.get('username');
```

`get` method is not supported in internet explorer.Then how can we retrive the `username` in internet explorer?

Comment: That depends on why you need form data? Most likely, use a form data polyfill such as https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/blob/9b77a24f58c72fcd15e955e26c5a745ca08b2575/src/javascript/xhr/FormData.js

Comment: Why not use ajax call ?

Comment: Its better to use ajax call for submitting stuffs over ajax. I found it better than FormData().

Comment: @AlexandruMihai One of the reasons for `FormData` is to make it easier to [submit form data using AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: I found here that is not supported ! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get

Comment: Why would you need to retrieve something that you just set a line before? You already know the value.

Comment: @CBroe This is just a sample code.For me the case is different.I need to validate a file format that is sent through formdata.

Comment: What do you mean by “sent through formdata”? Are you not creating the FormData object yourself, but get it passed in from the outside somewow …?

Comment: View:
var bulkUploadFile = $('#bulkImportCSV').files[0];
var data = new FormData();
data.append("bulkupload", bulkUploadFile);
uploadBulkAssignments.uploadFile(data, function () {

                });

Model:
  uploadFile: function(file) {


            if (file.get("bulkupload").name.split(".")[1] === "csv") {}
}


Here file is the formdata.Am validating formdata's file name here.But get method is not working in ie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of it yourself with what values you are adding or you can use this solid [polyfill](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData) that has all the methods

Then if you want to convert it to native you could just loop over the entries and append it to the native formData

## Non of this is working in IE:

Some option are `entries(), getAll(), keys(), values()` but non of them are working cuz append is the only thing IE can do...

Other option to retrieve it is by using `Array.from(formdata)` or the simpler version `[...formdata]` but that requires entries (aka Iterator)

There is also another solution to get all the fields without any way to get it from formData. And that is by using `fetch` where as you can convert a formData to a blob, arrayBuffer or text

`new Response(formdata).text().then(console.log)`

But the problem are IE don't have support for `fetch`

Comment: I don't think `Array.from(FormData)` works on any of the browsers that lack `FormData.get`.

Comment: @12Me21 No, IE11 doesn't support Array.from.